# If...then...Elseif statement reverting back to first statement

Tags: vb.net

I have a settings file named My.Settings.StirProfile. I load values by index into textboxes when a certain time in seconds has elapsed.To control the conditions I use a If...then...Elseif statement to load the values.

I have tried the following:

LblTime.Text = time in seconds and is updated by a timer

```
 If LblTime.Text <= My.Settings.StirProfile(1) Then

                    stirrVal.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(0)

                    Label12.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(1)' Val = 58 sec
                    Label13.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(0)' Val = 100 rpm

                   
                    'step2
                ElseIf LblTime.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(3) Then

                    stirrVal.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(2)

                    Label12.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(3)' val = 60 sec
                    Label13.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(2)' val= 110 rpm

                   
                    'step3

                ElseIf LblTime.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(5) Then

                    stirrVal.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(4)

                    Label12.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(5) ' val= 80 sec
                    Label13.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(4) ' val = 120 rpm

                   
                    'step4

                ElseIf LblTime.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(7) Then

                    stirrVal.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(6)

                   
                    Label12.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(7)' val= 110 sec
                    Label13.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(6) ' val = 140 rpm

                    
                    'step5

                ElseIf LblTime.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(9) Then

                    stirrVal.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(8)

                   Label12.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(9)
                    Label13.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(8)
               

end if
```

In Step 4 I am expecting 110 and 140 but it reverts back to step 1 index 0 and index 1 although index  6 and 7 is required by code...

If I place this code in a separate button, I get the correct values:

```
 Label12.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(7)' val= 110 sec
                    Label13.Text = My.Settings.StirProfile(6) ' val = 140 rpm
```

I am puzzled here....What is causing this behavior?

[Settings file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otun5.png)

Comment: It sounds like you need to debug your code properly, setting a breakpoint at the top of the code, stepping through it line by line and examining the state at each step.

Comment: Would suspect the problem is around the time being converted then stored as a string in lblTime.  What types exactly have you defined your project settings as?

Answer (score 1):

Looks spaghetti code to me, there are different concerns here and all are intermixed.

- Reading stir profiles
- Deciding what to do based on an input value
- Setting values to UI controls
- (Reading values form UI controls)
- Periodically refreshing UI

I also strongly suggest you put the project settings (as well as the visual studio defaults) to `Option Strict On` and `Option Explicit On` which shows you where you have conversion issues (which is - as @Hursey states it - likely your problem).

Here my proposal of how you could restructure it:

Make a separate class `StirProfile` like this (nothing special here):

```
Public Class StirProfile

    Public Sub New(timeInSeconds As Int32, rotationsPerMinute As Int32)
        Me.TimeInSeconds = timeInSeconds
        Me.RotationsPerMinute = rotationsPerMinute
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property TimeInSeconds As Int32

    Public ReadOnly Property RotationsPerMinute As Int32

End Class
```

Make a separate class `StirProfileProvider` that reads the settings and converts them into your domain model:

- When I added the `Settings.settings` it caused some problems and I had to add it with a different name so here it is called `AppSettings.settings` and the hierarchy is slightly different: `My.AppSettings.Default.StirProfile` instead of `My.Settings.StirProfile`.
- The class depends on extension methods shown later.
- I copied the XML code generated by the settings from app.config and pasted it into a private property as `XElement`, using VB.NET's inline XML features to provide a working sample configuration in the error message in case an exception occurs.

  ```
   Imports System.Configuration

   Public NotInheritable Class StirProfileProvider

       Public Shared Function GetStirProfiles() As List(Of StirProfile)
           Dim result As New List(Of StirProfile)(5)
           'Assumes the values are stored in a single settings value called 'StirProfile' of type 'StringCollection'
           Try
               With My.AppSettings.Default.StirProfile
                   For i As Int32 = 0 To 8
                       Dim rotationsPerMinute As String = .Item(i)
                       i += 1
                       Dim timeInSeconds As String = .Item(i)
                       result.Add(timeInSeconds, rotationsPerMinute)
                   Next
               End With
           Catch ex As Exception
               Throw New ConfigurationErrorsException($"Configuration error in the application's configuration file. Please ensure the StirProfiles are configured similar to this: {vbCrLf}{vbCrLf}{SampleConfig}", ex)
           End Try
           Return result
       End Function

       Private Shared ReadOnly Property SampleConfig As XElement = <applicationSettings>
                                                                       <SampleApp.AppSettings>
                                                                           <setting name="StirProfile" serializeAs="Xml">
                                                                               <value>
                                                                                   <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                                                                                       <string>100</string>
                                                                                       <string>58</string>
                                                                                       <string>110</string>
                                                                                       <string>60</string>
                                                                                       <string>120</string>
                                                                                       <string>80</string>
                                                                                       <string>140</string>
                                                                                       <string>110</string>
                                                                                       <string>150</string>
                                                                                       <string>120</string>
                                                                                   </ArrayOfString>
                                                                               </value>
                                                                           </setting>
                                                                       </SampleApp.AppSettings>
                                                                   </applicationSettings>

   End Class
  ```

Create a module `StirProfileExtension` that contains the extension methods mentioned earlier:

- Main focus here is validation and exception handling during the conversions

  ```
   Imports System.Globalization
   Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

   Public Module StirProfileExtension

       <Extension()>
       Public Sub Add(list As IList(Of StirProfile), timeInSeconds As String, rotationsPerMinute As String)
           If (list Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(list))
           If (timeInSeconds Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(timeInSeconds))
           If (rotationsPerMinute Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(rotationsPerMinute))

           Dim myTimeInSeconds As Int32
           Try
               myTimeInSeconds = Int32.Parse(timeInSeconds, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           Catch ex As Exception
               Throw New ArgumentException($"The given value of '{timeInSeconds}' cannot be converted into a positive Int32!", NameOf(timeInSeconds), ex)
           End Try

           Dim myRotationsPerMinute As Int32
           Try
               myRotationsPerMinute = Int32.Parse(rotationsPerMinute, NumberStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
           Catch ex As Exception
               Throw New ArgumentException($"The given value of '{rotationsPerMinute}' cannot be converted into a positive Int32!", NameOf(rotationsPerMinute), ex)
           End Try

           list.Add(myTimeInSeconds, myRotationsPerMinute)
       End Sub

       <Extension()>
       Public Sub Add(list As IList(Of StirProfile), timeInSeconds As Int32, rotationsPerMinute As Int32)
           If (list Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(list))
           Dim element As New StirProfile(timeInSeconds, rotationsPerMinute)
           list.Add(element)
       End Sub

   End Module
  ```

And then the form could look something like this:

- The timer event only refreshes the UI control, the property `TimeInSeconds` calculates itself.
- Property `StirProfilesSorted` caches the sorted list of `StirProfiles` (this may be good or bad: Better performance but configuration changes are not reflected until the application is restarted).
- Method `YourMethod()` is the left-over of what you posted above.

  ```
   Imports System.Globalization

   Public Class Form1

       Private Stopwatch As New Stopwatch()
       Private LastTimeInSeconds As Int32 = -1
       Private _StirProfilesSorted As List(Of StirProfile)

       Public Sub New()
           ' This call is required by the designer.
           InitializeComponent()
           ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
           Stopwatch.Start()
           Timer1.Start()
       End Sub

       Private ReadOnly Property TimeInSeconds As Int32
           Get
               Return CInt(Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds \ 1000)
           End Get
       End Property

       Private ReadOnly Property StirProfilesSorted As List(Of StirProfile)
           Get
               Dim result As List(Of StirProfile) = _StirProfilesSorted
               If (result Is Nothing) Then
                   result = (From e In StirProfileProvider.GetStirProfiles() Order By e.TimeInSeconds).ToList()
                   _StirProfilesSorted = result
               End If
               Return result
           End Get
       End Property

       Private Sub YourMethod()
           Dim stirProfile As StirProfile = GetCurrentStirProfile(TimeInSeconds)
           Dim rotationsPerMinuteDisplayString As String = stirProfile.RotationsPerMinute.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
           Dim timeInSecondsDisplayString As String = stirProfile.TimeInSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
           stirrVal.Text = rotationsPerMinuteDisplayString
           Label13.Text = rotationsPerMinuteDisplayString
           Label12.Text = timeInSecondsDisplayString
       End Sub

       Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
           Dim myTimeInSeconds = TimeInSeconds
           If (myTimeInSeconds <> LastTimeInSeconds) Then
               LastTimeInSeconds = myTimeInSeconds
               LblTime.Text = myTimeInSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
               YourMethod()
           End If
       End Sub

       Private Function GetCurrentStirProfile(timeInSeconds As Int32) As StirProfile
           Dim result As StirProfile = (From e In StirProfilesSorted Where timeInSeconds <= e.TimeInSeconds).FirstOrDefault()
           If (result Is Nothing) Then
               Return StirProfilesSorted.Last()
           End If
           Return result
       End Function

   End Class
  ```